# Is there a way to check to see if an array contains another array in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write an postgresql query and one of the where statements is a check to see if an array of filters that a user passes contains a value the array of types on a database column has in a json blob.
for example, if the user sets their filters to look for values
`["prettyfly","likespizza"]`

and the table has

`["eatingfood","prettyfly"]`

in a column it would return that row. Here is what I've tried, but it isn't quite right

```
filterQuery = `AND ['${coreValueFilters.join("','")}'] = ANY(hashtags)`
```

hashtags being the name of the table.

Here is a clearer example without variables

```
filterQuery = `AND ["prettyfly","likespizza"] = ANY(hashtags)`
```

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `select array['prettyfly', 'likespizza'] && array['eatingfood', 'prettyfly']; t`? Per [Array Functions/operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html).

Comment: Yes I think that is it. The only piece I am missing now is making the query see the jsonb of (hashtags) as an array

Comment: `select '["prettyfly", "likespizza"]'::jsonb ?| array['eatingfood', 'prettyfly']; t`. [JSON functions/operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I got that works
`AND hashtags ?| ARRAY['${coreValueFilters.join("','")}']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&`

> anyarray && anyarray → boolean
> Do the arrays overlap, that is, have any elements in common?
> ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1] → t

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Comment: I think this works, the only piece missing now is that it doesn't like the column being a jsonb. I tried

ERROR: function json_array_elements(jsonb)

Comment: Then again your question description is incomplete. Nowhere did you mention you are using `jsonb`. Your examples show using Postgres `array` which is a different thing.